Pig-related die probability question
Two players, A and B, alternately throwing one six-sided dice, the winner being that player whose cumulative total reaches or exceeds $T$ points. What is the approximate probability that A wins?
It seems that the answer is $$\varphi\left(\frac{t_a-t_b+7/4} {\sqrt{5/6(t_a+t_b)}}\right)$$
where $\varphi$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution, and $t_a,t_b$ is the number of points short of the goal $T$ for players $A,B$ respectively. The reasoning goes as follows but I'm not sure I understand it well, so any help in deciphering it would be appreciated:
After $n=2/7(t_a+t_b)$ throws, the standard deviation is $\sqrt{\frac{35}{12}n}=\sqrt{\frac{5}{6}(t_a+t_b)}$. The advantage of having the next throw is equal to 1/2 the average number
of points to be gained: $t_a - t_b + 7/4$.
We wish to determine the probability $P(x)$ that the player’s opponent fails
to gain this number of points in $2(t_a - t_b)/7$ throws. Accordingly, we set $$x=\frac{t_a-t_b+7/4}{\sqrt{5/6(t_a+t_b)}}$$and $P(x)=\varphi\left(\frac{t_a-t_b+7/4}{\sqrt{5/6(t_a+t_b)}}\right)$. The points I'm confused about, shouldn't the advantage of having the next throw be $7/2$, and how did we make a statement about $P(x)$? Like why does the so-called advantage have a mean of $0$ and std of $\sqrt{5/6(t_a+t_b)}$ as implicitly implied by applying the CLT above?

Do you have a source for that solution?

@Wei recitation notes from a probability class I'm taking.

For those who may not know: pig is a  dice game.
